# Sequence Word Problem General Question

Tags: sequences-and-series

Whenever I do sequence word problems in my math homework I often end up accidentally adding 1 more term than needed, or subtracting 1 more term. Word problems seem ambiguous to me in wording a lot of the time and I don't know whether to do $(n-1)d$, or $nd$. Can anyone give some general guidelines as to when to use $(n-1)d$, or $nd$? I feel like I understand sequences well but once word problems come into play no matter how much practice I put in, I add or subtract a term extra.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example of such a problem? I'm not quite sure what you mean by a sequence word problem.

Comment: E.g., boxes are stacked in a store display in the shape of a triangle. The number of boxes in the rows form an arithmetic sequence. There are 41 boxes in the 3rd row from the bottom. There are 23 boxes in the 12th row from the bottom. How many boxes are there in the first (bottom) row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer specific to the example in the comments:

To find the difference between each row we can use the information about rows 3 and 12. We know that row three has 41 boxes, and row 12 has 23 boxes. Since we have an arithmetic progression, this means that 
$$
41+(12-3)n=23,
$$
or $n=-2$. Thus when you go up one row, you lose $2$ boxes. Note that we used $12-3=9$, because in going from row $3$ to row $12$ we *moved upwards nine times*. Even though there are 10 rows in this interval, we wish to keep track of the number of times we change rows. This I hope gets to the heart of your question. So now that we know $n=-2$, lets find the number of boxes in row $1$. Note that in going from row $3$ to row $1$, we move downwards twice. Thus our answer is $41+(1-3)*-2=45$.

A last piece of advice: when the number of rows or terms in your sequence is small, draw pictures! It is a great way to build intuition doing these problems,  and can be nice to check your work.

Hope this helps!